# Circular alignment of ImageView's

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-gesture

Hello Stack Overflow community!

I am developing a card game on Android. In each round, each player will have a deck of 5 cards. Each card will be a different ImageView. I would like to align the cards in a circular order as in the figure: [Figure1: What I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKx84.png)

Some cards may go out of screen a bit but the player would swipe the deck to left or to right and the images would move in a circular way. My questions are:

1) How to make the layout allow "out of bounds" for ImageViews. I tried using `android:clipChildren="false"` and `android:clipToPadding="false"` but it won't work for the right side of the screen (Image scales itself to fit in the screen)

2) What would be the easiest way to achieve the "circular swiping". I have experience on 3D programming so I know that I would use sin and cos to calculate the coordinates, however I have to deal with margins as it is a Layout and I don't know how to keep things "responsive".

Thank you!

Comment: You may be better off not dealing with image views, but going for a custom view and drawing everything with openGL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problem, I ended up using [this library](https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView).